# Monthly subscription - Simple Commerce

Tags: safecracker, ecommerce, zoo-visitor, status, payment-gateway

I have created Zoo visitor members to have the ability to upload only one entry via safecracker with status **close** (Which I can do that). They will be allowed to tweak the content whatever they like.

I am hoping to find a way, to create a monthly payment to switch the status to **open** to make it visible to public.

Before I develop anything. I saw the price for Cartthob Subscription which is very steep and cannot afford right now. I would like to know if it possible to work with Simple Commerce, has anyone done this before or offer me a guidance.

Looking above at my request which looks really simple, $299 is too steep for this Cartthob Subscription feature.

ps: I do not have any experience with payment gateways setup.

Many thanks

Comment: There is also the Membrr add-on avilable at http://membrr.com

Comment: Beware that Membrr is very complicated to set up properly and people are reporting that support can be patchy at times.

Answer (score 1):

In EE2 Simple Commerce can do monthly payments also but does not have the functionality to open/close channel entries.[image] Also it only works with a PayPal account (and if I remember correctly) the PayPal Standard API which requires an IPN notification to be sent out and received for the system to mark items as paid. That API is notoriously buggy.

As Ian mentioned there is also [CartThrob](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/cartthrob2) + [Subscriptions](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/subscriptions) but it will total in at $600 if you do not already have license to either pieces of software. Having said that $600 is still between 10-100 times cheaper then developing something for yourself.

From your original post if you want something integrated into EE that is not going to break the bank your best bet would be [Membrr](http://membrr.com). It can be a slight pain to set up as the actual Payment Gateway system requires IonCube installed on the server.

Comment: Sorry, it'd been a long time since I last looked at Simple Commerce and didn't realise it had a subscription feature. Funnily enough I was working on a site today that had it and I realised I'd given the wrong advice regarding it in my previous reply.

Comment: No worries Tyseen :)

Comment: Justin, that's okay if status does not work. Looking at the image provided, looks it got the ability move a member to new member group after a successful payment? Does it also have the ability to revert the member group from subscription cancellation?

Comment: Actually I am going to vomit after reading the Paypal setup settings. Going to purchase Carthrob Subscription, also got Carthrob a while ago but never used it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

> Looking above at my request which looks really simple, $299 is too steep for this Cartthob Subscription feature.

You should try developing it yourself then. When you're done (I'll guess in about a year) let us know how much you want to sell it for :)

$299 is a bargain for that piece of software. If you aren't covering that cost with the price of a few subscriptions (or at the very least saving a few billable hours of your time), you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Haha true, well I am actually hoping to cover the cost if I get some traffic.

Answer (score 0):

No, Simple Commerce can't do subscriptions.

Like Justin says you can use Membrr but it's still going to cost $145. In my experience of using Membrr, the extra you'd pay for Cartthrob is worth it for the hassle you get from using Membrr, although support from Cartthrob is a bit of an issue at the moment.

> Looking above at my request which looks really simple, $299 is too steep for this Cartthob Subscription feature.

It might look simple, but it's not, and $300 is a fair price for the amount of work it would save you if you were to develop it yourself.

Comment: Okay I will give it a go.

Comment: Not going to downvote ;)